# Early and earlier

Tags: word-usage

I would like to ask about the the words early and earlier if I have this situation( I speak with someone and she expect to receive something from someone before one week from her flight for example)

In this case is it right to say:

1. if you didn’t receive it before one week **earlier**. Call me.
2. if you didn’t receive it before one week **early**. Call me.

Comment: If you didn’t receive it **a week ago**. Call me. Before one week is not grammatical in English.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to say this is:

> If you don't receive this one week before your flight, then call me.

You shouldn't use past tense, unless you are trying to say:

> If you did not receive this one week before your flight, then you
>   should have called me.

Answer (score 0):

I would say:

> One week before your flight, if you have not received (the item your friend is waiting for), call me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you *do* mean to say.

The following are more or less synonymous:

> One week before your flight
>
> One week earlier than your flight

You don't need both, and in fact it reads very oddly to do so. (You could say *earlier, before your flight*, but there *earlier* would mean "at a time before something we have already been talking about", not relating it to the flight, so *before your flight* in addition makes sense).

As to the difference between *early* and *earlier*: in most uses *earlier* simply means *at a time before*, as a plain factual statement. *Early* generally implies a standard: it means something like *earlier than expected* or *earlier than required*.